# Add minute in Timestamp with out using Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I have Timestamp Object and I want to add minute in this object, I achieve this functionality as follow :

```
int validTime =  60 ; // In minutes
Timestamp createDate =  groupData.getCreateDate(); // fetch from DB
long time = createDate.getTime() + (validTime*60*1000);
Timestamp expiryTime = new Timestamp(time);
```

This code works properly but I can achieve this by using Calendar object also, so which should I use ?

Comment: JDBC time stamp is for more of JDBC usage ."A thin wrapper around java.util.Date that allows the JDBC API to identify this as an SQL TIMESTAMP value. It adds the ability to hold the SQL TIMESTAMP fractional seconds value, by allowing the specification of fractional seconds to a precision of nanoseconds. A Timestamp also provides formatting and parsing operations to support the JDBC escape syntax for timestamp values."

Comment: One happens when you move past 59 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(yourInitialTimestamp);
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, validTime);
```

If you are going to do a lot more in terms of calculation of date/time/etc, take a look at [YodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).